# Exportar datos de una fecha a otra fecha con codeignter

Tags: codeigniter

Hola quisiera saber como podría exportar desde una fecha a otra fecha a un Excel. Estoy realizando una aplicación web con codeigniter que una persona registra a un usuario y se guarda en base de datos ,eso en una ventana, pero hay otra que solo hay 2 input que son datepicker con fecha desde y fecha hasta.Lo que quisiera es saber como puedo hacer que al momento que presiono el botón de exportar  exporte desde una fecha en particular que haya puesto a otra con todos usuarios que se han registrado en esos días.

[image: Os dejo la]

Os dejo también el código donde pongo los campos de fecha desde y hasta

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="tab-content">
           <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class=" col-md-2">
               <label for="fdesde">Fecha desde</label>
               <input type="text" name="fdesde" id="fdesde" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime('-1 month',strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))) )?>">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-2">
               <label for="fhasta">Fecha hasta</label>
               <input type="text" name="fhasta" id="fhasta" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y') ?>">
           </div>
```

El boton de exportar

```
              <a href = "" id="exportar" class="btn btn-success centro">Exportar a Excel</a>
```

Primera ventana

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segunda Ventana
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si ayude un poco, pero quisera saber como hacer esa exportacion por fechas. Gracias.

Comment: Que has intentado, seria bueno que agregaras código de tu controlador y de tu modelo para saber que has tratado de realizar y en base a eso ayudarte. Porque hasta el código de tu vista esta demasiado simple y no muestras el form completo para saber con que método lo estas enviando y a que función del controlador.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes razón, no agregue el código del controlador y del modelo porque creo no que esta bien.
CONTROLADOR :

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Exportacion extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('empleado_model');
     $this->load->library('excel');
    }
    //CARGA DE LAS VISTAS Y DEL TITULO POR VARIABLE
    public function index()
    {
        $data['title']='Gallery Hoteles';
        $this->load->view('comun/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('exporta_views',$data);
        $this->load->view('comun/footer',$data);
    }
    public function to_excel()
    {
        $exportar = $this->empleado_model->get_to_excel();
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
        $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
        $objPHPExcel->
        getProperties()
            ->setTitle("Listado de clientes")
            ->setSubject("Clientes")
            ->setDescription("Exportación de Clientes")
            ->setKeywords("exportacion, clientes")
            ->setCategory("clientes");
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Id')
            ->setCellValue('B1', 'Nombre')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Primer apellido')
            ->setCellValue('D1', 'Segundo apellido')
            ->setCellValue('E1', 'Email')
            ->setCellValue('F1', 'Ciudad')
            ->setCellValue('G1', 'Empleado')
            ->setCellValue('H1', 'Fecha')
            ->setCellValue('I1', 'Condiciones');

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(10);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(70);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(70);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(70);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(70);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(1);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setAutoSize(70);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setAutoSize(70);
        $i = 2;

        foreach ($exportar as $row){
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $row->idCliente)
                ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $row->nombre)
                ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $row->papellido)
                ->setCellValue('D'.$i,$row->sapellido)
                ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $row->emial)
                ->setCellValue('F'.$i, $row->ciudad)
                ->setCellValue('G'.$i, $row->empleado)
                ->setCellValue('H'.$i, $row->fecha)
                ->setCellValue('I'.$i, $row->condiciones);
                $i =  $i+1;
        }
    }
}
```

MODELO:

```html
<?php
class Empleado_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function insertar($data)
    {
         $this->db->insert('cliente', $data);
    }
    public function get_to_excel($exportar)
    {
        $this->db->select(array('c.idCliente','c.nombre','c.apellido','c.sapellido','c.email','c.ciudad','c.empleado','c.fecha','c.condiciones'));
        $this->db->form('cliente as c');
        $query = $this->db->get();
          return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

VISTA:

```html
<form method="post" id="exportar_form">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="tab-content">
               <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                   <label for="fdesde">Fecha desde</label>
                   <input type="text" name="fdesde" id="fdesde" class="form-control" style="cursor: default" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime('-1 month',strtotime(date('d-m-Y'))) )?>">
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-2">
                   <label for="fhasta">Fecha hasta</label>
                   <input type="text" name="fhasta" id="fhasta" class="form-control" style="cursor: default" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y')?>">
               </div>
           </div>
           <br>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5"></div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success exportar" name="exportar" value="<?php echo (base_url('exportacion/to_excel'))?>">
</form>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="col-lg-5 "></div>
              <a href = "<?php echo base_url('empleado')?>" id="exportar" class="btn btn-info centro">Volver </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    $(function (){
        $('#fdesde').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            autoclose:true,
            language: 'es',
            firstDay: 1
        });
        $('#fhasta').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            autoclose:true,
            firstDay: 1,
            language: 'es', firstDay: 1});
    });

</script>
```